# How do you turn on a battery and a timer using a single mechanical switch action?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, circuit-design, schematics, layout

I am adding a 12V battery to a circuit where I previously used a transformer power supply. The circuit works well but is unused for extended periods of time and there is an issue with the LED display on the timer controller slowly drawing down the battery.

So in order to preserve the battery without physically disconnecting the battery I'm trying to create the following sequence of events with a single push of a button (normally off switch):

1. battery turns on
2. timer turns on and device is activated
3. timer turns off and device is deactivated
4. battery turns off

Is there a simple way to do this?

A latch circuit looks like a potential solution (https://electronoobs.com/eng_circuitos_tut61.php)

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,

[image: schematic]

Comment: Can 1 and 2 occur simultaneously. Ditto 3 and 4?

Comment: replace the pushbutton and the timer module with a mechanical timer

Comment: Why not a pressure switch? Once the pressure goes below X then it turns on…

Answer (score 0):

A 12V true off-delay timer may be used instead.

[image]

When push button switch 'S1' is momentarily pressed, the timer is energised and its

contact 'K1' closes to start the pump motor.

The pump motor stops when contact 'K1' opens after the set time.

Comment: Does the circuit disconnect from the power supply entirely after the pump stops (k1 opens)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Can this be done with the timer in the picture?

Comment: Which timer are you referring to?

Comment: The blue timer above in the schematic in the original question. That is the actual timer I'm using. Thanks

Comment: No, since it draws power even when it's idle unlike a true off-delay timer that doesn't.